# NetSuite Inventory Detail Error on Transfer Order Transform

Tags: netsuite, suitescript

I keep getting the same error "The total inventory detail quantity must be 1." when running this Suitelet. I tried everything I can imagine but no luck getting it to work. If anyone can help, you'd have my eternal gratitude!

```
var fulfillment_record = nlapiTransformRecord('transferorder', 534568, 'itemfulfillment',  {recordmode: 'dynamic'});

        fulfillment_record.selectLineItem('item', 1);

        fulfillment_record.setCurrentLineItemValue('item', 'itemreceive', 'T');
        fulfillment_record.setCurrentLineItemValue('item', 'quantity', 1);          

        var subrecord = fulfillment_record.createCurrentLineItemSubrecord('item', 'inventorydetail');
            subrecord.selectNewLineItem('inventoryassignment');
                subrecord.setCurrentLineItemValue('inventoryassignment', 'quantity', 1);
                subrecord.setCurrentLineItemValue('inventoryassignment', 'binnumber', 134);             
            subrecord.commitLineItem('inventoryassignment');
            subrecord.commit();

        fulfillment_record.commitLineItem('item');

    var id = nlapiSubmitRecord(fulfillment_record, true, false);
```

Answer (score 0):

Was told my support this is a bug in 2.0! Workaround is to delete the IF and recreate it with the correct quantity

Answer (score 0):

Also could be that that binnumber is:

- is not avail to your location
- is not in inventory
- fields not set in proper order being that you are in dynamic mode

Answer (score 0):

When we do Transform the data from the parent record will be available in the child record.
The inventoryassignment will also be available in the child record so you can remove all the lines from inventoryassignment and then add the values you require.

This is a sample SuiteScript 2.0

```js
let invItemSubRec = workOrderBuild.getCurrentSublistSubrecord(
    {
        sublistId: 'component',
        fieldId: 'componentinventorydetail',
    }
);
//Remove lines from sublistSubRecord if they alredy exists.
const lineCount = invItemSubRec.getLineCount({
    sublistId: 'inventoryassignment'
});
if (lineCount > 0) {
    for (var lineIndex = 0; lineIndex < lineCount; lineIndex++) {
        invItemSubRec.removeLine({
            sublistId: 'inventoryassignment',
            line: lineIndex,
            ignoreRecalc: true
        });
    }
}
// set inventoryassignment line values
```

Comment: The code you posted is *not* a runnable snippet (just click the "Run..." button and you will realize that)! Please edit your answer and format your code as a **plain code block** instead (use simple, three back-tick code fences).